# AJAX not passing variables on Server (Any AJAX)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, .htaccess

So i have a lot of AJAX functions, they worked all well all good in server as well as in localhost until recently i made some changes in the js files and some ajax-php files as well. Nevertheless...they are still working absolutely fine on localhost...but not on server

During debugging, i found out...that the ajax has no problem getting the file....i mean there is no 404 error....however....it isn't passing the variable...

**JS FILE**

```
function nextImg(Imgkey){
changeImgViewerN = 0;
var currUrl = window.location.href;
var baseUrl = currUrl.split(/[\\/]/).pop();
var splitUrl = baseUrl.split('&');
var folderKey = splitUrl.pop();
var groupKey = splitUrl[0];
if(groupKey == undefined) groupKey = folderKey;
   $.ajax({
      url:'/9712d9c1_2be4d8c9318e69_1b526557b8_sF',
      type: 'POST',
      data:{searchNextImg:Imgkey, groupKey:groupKey, folderKey:folderKey},
      success: function(response){
        $('#in_folders').prepend(response);
      }
   })
}
```

**PHP FILE**

```
echo "Here";
if(isset($_POST['searchNextImg']) || isset($_POST['searchPrevImg'])) && isset($_POST['groupKey']) && isset($_POST['folderKey'])){

    echo "Reading";
}
```

However on the server, it just executes
*echo "Here";*
but not
*echo "Reading";*

My .htaccess file says:

```
RewriteRule ^9712d9c1_2be4d8c9318e69_1b526557b8_sF$ http://www.example.com/ajaxinc/searchFile.php
```

There are such other AJAX functions but they are not passing variables to the server, however on localhost, they are working perfectly. All of them.

Comment: How you pass this `$_POST['searchPrevImg']` from your ajax ??

Comment: replace ; with , after type: 'POST'

Comment: It was a typing mistake....and there is an **OR** condition in PHP so it doesn't matter. I have a different function for passing that. @Saty

Comment: Below `echo "Here"; `, write `echo json_encode($_POST); ` and check what values are in POST.

Comment: try to print something in the else, because the error could be in the if condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace:

```
url:'/9712d9c1_2be4d8c9318e69_1b526557b8_sF',
```

with

```
url:'9712d9c1_2be4d8c9318e69_1b526557b8_sF',
```

You did not  pass this variable `searchPrevImg` in your ajax call, but that is in or condition so does not matter. 
suggestion:

use the below way to create data objects:

```
data:{'searchNextImg':Imgkey, 'groupKey':groupKey, 'folderKey':folderKey},
```

Comment: yes. I did not...therefore there is this **OR** operator in the php condition. And it ain't working :(

Comment: did you try all the things that i have mentioned in my answer?

Comment: you're `type: 'POST';` should be `type: 'POST',`

Comment: Okay it worked...but i also had to change the .htaccess file and remove http://www.example.com....could u please explain your answer?

Comment: what exactly are you asking me to explain?

Comment: Why removing the "/" worked? I mean "/" is supposed to mean that it is relative to the root directory ie www.example.com and not relative to the current directory...ie www.example.com/current/dir then why removing it worked?

Comment: because in your .htaccess file `9712d9c1_2be4d8c9318e69_1b526557b8_sF`  already refers to this url   `http://www.example.com/ajaxinc/searchFile.php`, which is already url from root. So you should not use `/` to refer to a root url that is already a root url :)

Comment: Yes. I understand that. However doing the same thing to css and other js files don't work. I mean....If i reference css file as rel="ablkjdsf.css" which is also defined in the .htaccess file as root file...it doesn't work in directories like www.example.com/curr/dif...so i had to make that rel="/ablkjds.css" to make it work everywhere.

Comment: you need to define rules of that as well in your `.htaccess` or find other way to refer to the url whichever is convenient to you.

Answer (score 1):

You have a js syntax error:

Replace: `type: 'POST';` by `type: 'POST',`

The rest of the code looks well.

Answer (score 0):

try to make your ajax call like below.

```
 $.ajax({
  url:'/9712d9c1_2be4d8c9318e69_1b526557b8_sF',
  type: 'POST',
  data:{searchNextImg:Imgkey, groupKey:groupKey, folderKey:folderKey},
  async:false,
  success: function(response){
    $('#in_folders').prepend(response);
  }
   })
```

Comment: `async: false`? Why reason?

Comment: may be server is taking too long time to respond. so killing the default behavior of ajax to figure out the exact issue. In my case this happened.

Comment: That is just what happens if you use a non-async operation. I mean, while the server does not answer, the browser will freeze waiting for the response. Opening the developer tools, network tab, you can see all requests (including ajax request), so it's better to debug 